Meaning of 注意点你的脑袋！
see https://www.163.com/dy/article/J079AOTE0543A3A8.html
Some users think it means "you must be crazy (nuts, have your head examined)": 注意 can mean "look out for" see e.g. trainchinese.com, 人在气头上就怕激，1995年盖州市城关镇“8·19”凶杀案侦破始末 or "you better have your head examined"

因小故而殺人的案件連年不斷，跟泛濫的受害者心態有關，不少人只知 "人人對自已有惡意，個個在逼害自己"，繼而狂性大發，政府應加強人民教育，萬事先反省，不可事事都怪罪別人

注意点你的脑袋, (in a general context), is a very common euphemistic phrase used as a threat of physical violence. In the old days, perhaps even now, the way to execute an enemy is beheading. And so, asking someone to 注意点你的脑袋, "pay some attention to your head", is to say, if your don't, you may lose it, (i.e. your head); just like if you don't pay attention to your, say, iPhone, you may lose it.

I think it means “watch your head” (if you do that, you’ll get beheaded/hit on the head), which is a threat.

赵世昌听到这里上去就给赵世海一个脖子拐

So later 赵世昌 indeed slapped 赵世海 on the back of the head.

你到汽水厂卖, 注意点你的脑袋!
(If/When) you go to the soda water factory to sell, watch out! (you are risking your life)

it was a threat.
The literal meaning of the sentence was "watch out for your head". 注意 here could be equal to 小心.
The real meaning was "watch out for  your head. If your don't do that and then you'll lose it(which means you will die)." The sentence and others similar to this one(like 下班后你给我小心点, 走路的时候注意点 etc) were always used when in arguments and fights to make a threat.
